# Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'xyz' in 'field list'

Tags: sql, node.js

```
insert into model(categoryid, subcategoryid, companyid, modelid, vendor, registrationno, color, fueltype, average, capacity, feature, remark, stat, icon) 
 code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
  errno: 1054,
  sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'vendor' in 'field list'",
  sqlState: '42S22',
  index: 0,
  sql: values('44','8','4','2','102','MP077SHGS','RED','xyz','8','5','WQOI','WQHJ','continue','6102e254-2248-4bc3-a7a5-6c0c8da71475.png')
```

i don't find any correct solution

Comment: Mysql is not SQL server - please correct your tags

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags; you'll need to (re)tag appropriately using the [edit] feature.

Answer (score 0):

The database table that you are inserting into is missing the 'vendor' field.  You can verify what is there with a 'show columns in model'.

Comment: yes vendor column show in database

Comment: Can you post the output from 'show columns in model'?